# Change the string and replace it in the specific index that I search for it and make new string

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, replace, startswith

I have a SDP file and I convert it to string like bellow:

```
v=0
o=- 1443716955 1443716955 IN IP4 10.20.130.110
m=video 20000 RTP/AVP 96 // <== this line 
c=IN IP4 239.0.1.2/64
a=source-filter: incl IN IP4 239.0.1.2 192.168.0.1
a=rtpmap:96 raw/90000
a=mid:primary
m=video 20000 RTP/AVP 96 // <== this line 
c=IN IP4 239.0.1.3/64
a=source-filter: incl IN IP4 239.0.1.3 192.168.0.1
```

And in this line " m=video 20000 RTP/AVP 96 " I want to change **'20000'** to **'4321'**,I wrote this bellow code:

```
 let fileds= inputString .split(/\s+/);
    for(const field of fields) {
     if(field === "m=video") {

      }
     if (field === "m=audio") {
          var myflag = "au";
     }
    }
```

and above ode give me this bellow result:

```
m=video 4321 RTP/AVP 96
m=video 4321 RTP/AVP 96
```

I just want change them and replace to the string(like new string),Imagine I need result like bellow:

```
v=0
o=- 1443716955 1443716955 IN IP4 10.20.130.110
m=video 4321 RTP/AVP 96 // <== this line
c=IN IP4 239.0.1.2/64
a=source-filter: incl IN IP4 239.0.1.2 192.168.0.1
a=rtpmap:96 raw/90000
a=mid:primary
m=video 4321 RTP/AVP 96 //<== this line
c=IN IP4 239.0.1.3/64
a=source-filter: incl IN IP4 239.0.1.3 192.168.0.1
```

I totally new in java script, How I can replace it? because maybe I have another string with different "m=video" index in here 'm' in line 2 maybe in next string "m=video" on line 3 or 4.

Can I use ' string.startswith('m=video') ' and where I this code it true replace it with what I got it

EX : m=video 4321 RTP/AVP 96

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have an example:

Either simply using replace all `inputString.replace(/m=video 20000/g, "m=video 4321")`, where the g in `/m=video 20000/g` means replace globally (i.e. replace all).

Or we can map over each line and replace each line with `stringArr.map(str => str.replace(/m=video 20000/, "m=video 4321"))`

To make it dynamic (i.e. allow other numbers other than 20000) we can create a RegExp:

```
const inputNumberString = '20000'; //can be changed
const regex = new RegExp('m=video ' + inputNumberString, 'g');
const stringReplacedAll = inputString.replace(regex, "m=video 4321")
```

Or if the same pattern is always present but different numbers and you want to match any numbers you can use a RegExp pattern match like:

```
const inputPattern= /m=video \d{5}/g;
const stringReplacedAll = inputString.replace(inputPattern, "m=video 4321")
```

To change other parts of the string like the IP, do something like this:

```
const inputPattern= /m=video \d{5}/g;
const ipPattern = /c=IN IP4 \d{3}.\d.\d.\d\/\d{2}/g;
const stringReplacedAll = inputString
                    .replace(inputPattern, "m=video 4321")
                    .replace(ipPattern, "c=IN IP4 123.0.1.1/88");
```

Which matches any 5 digit number after `'m=video '`;

```js
const inputString = 
`v=0
o=- 1443716955 1443716955 IN IP4 10.20.130.110
m=video 20000 RTP/AVP 96 // <== this line 
c=IN IP4 239.0.1.2/64
a=source-filter: incl IN IP4 239.0.1.2 192.168.0.1
a=rtpmap:96 raw/90000
a=mid:primary
m=video 20000 RTP/AVP 96 // <== this line 
c=IN IP4 239.0.1.3/64
a=source-filter: incl IN IP4 239.0.1.3 192.168.0.1`;

const inputNumberString = '20000';
const inputPattern= /m=video \d{5}/g;
const ipPattern = /c=IN IP4 \d{3}.\d.\d.\d\/\d{2}/g;
const regex = new RegExp('m=video ' + inputNumberString, 'g');
const stringReplacedAll = inputString.replace(inputPattern, "m=video 4321").replace(ipPattern, "c=IN IP4 123.0.1.1/88");

console.log(stringReplacedAll);

//OR you can do it with array and map
const stringArr = inputString.split('\n');
const stringReplacedMap = stringArr.map(str => str.replace(/m=video 20000/, "m=video 4321")).join('\n');

//console.log(stringReplacedMap);
```

Comment: If '20000' isn't constant, How I can change it ?

Comment: I updated my answer. You need to start working with RegExp and can either construct the RegExp with your customer number string or you can match a pattern like 5 numbers. See my updated answer. Also, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp

Comment: If you have any questions let me know. Does my answer solve your problem?

Comment: That is wonderful,what about 'c' Do you have any idea about IP ?  I put this code it is similar with your code but didn't answer : const inputPatternC = /c=IN IP4 \d{4}/g;
    const regex_c = new RegExp('c=IN IP4 ' + FinalIP, 'g'); const stringReplacedC = stringReplacedMv.replace(inputPatternC, "c=IN IP4"+" "+ FinalIP);

Comment: You can use something like ``const ipPattern = /c=IN IP4 \d{3}.\d.\d.\d\/\d{2}/g;`` to pattern patch the IP string and replace it. See my updated answer. If I have solved your problem(s), please consider to up-vote and mark as accepted answer.